# location and firebase together not working

Tags: android, firebase

For FireBase I need to write in build.gradle(Module:app) the following line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when I write this, I get the following error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.
```

When I delete or comment these two lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
```

I get no error message, but I can't use the location function.

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/jsch-0.1.54.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
//last line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anybody help what the solution can be for this conflict?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make all your firebase and google play to be the same version

for example

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
```

Comment: I got this when I fixed what you wrote:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/mailcap
 File1:***\app\libs\mail-1.4.7.jar
 File2: ***\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.mail\mail\1.4.7\9add058589d5d85adeb625859bf2c5eeaaedf12d\mail-1.4.7.jar